# Why lager:info can not redirect output to another node's group_leader?

Tags: erlang

I want to redirect all output of other nodes into one main node.

The following code runs on the other node. `lager:info`'s output can not be found in the main node console, but `io:format`'s output can be found. Why?

```
-module(friar_sup).
-compile([{parse_transform, lager_transform}]).

-behaviour(supervisor).


test_a(Node)->
    true = group_leader(rpc:call(Node,erlang,whereis,[user]),self()),
    lager:info("friar_sup_test_a"),  %% <--------output cannot be found, why??
    io:format("friar_sup_test_b"),
    erlang:group_leader().
```

Comment: Not being a lager expert I guess it is because `lager:info` does not use the process group leader as default in the same way as `io:format`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Maybe you are right. Now I have to use many consoles for check nodes output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read the source of lager, it *should* be that the group leader of your process is where logs will be directed. They [test for this](https://github.com/basho/lager/blob/master/src/lager_console_backend.erl#L147) very thing. I'd take out an issue in their tracker for clarification: [here](https://github.com/basho/lager/issues).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read the test suites carefully and compare and try to find why two different results.